# Cumulative sales data with threshold value forming a new series / column with a boolean value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this type of data, but in real life it has millions of entries. Product id is always product specific, but occurs several times during its lifetime.

| date | product id | revenue | estimated lifetime value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-16 | 0061M00001AXc5lQAD | 970 | 2000 |
| 2021-04-17 | 0061M00001AXbCiQAL | 159 | 50000 |
| 2021-04-18 | 0061M00001AXb9AQAT | 80 | 3000 |
| 2021-04-19 | 0061M00001AXbIHQA1 | 1100 | 8000 |
| 2021-04-20 | 0061M00001AXbY8QAL | 90 | 4000 |
| 2021-04-21 | 0061M00001AXbQ1QAL | 29 | 30000 |
| 2021-04-21 | 0061M00001AXc5lQAD | 30 | 2000 |
| 2021-05-02 | 0061M00001AXc5lQAD | 50 | 2000 |
| 2021-05-05 | 0061M00001AXc5lQAD | 50 | 2000 |

I'm looking to create a new column in pandas that indicates when a certain product id has generated more revenue than a specific threshold e.g. 100$, 1000$, marking it as a Win (1). A win may occur only once during the lifecycle of a product. In addition I would want to create another column that would indicate the row where a specific product sales exceeds e.g. 10% of the estimated lifetime value.

What would be the most intuitive approach to achieve this in Python / Pandas?

edit:

- dw1k_thresh: if the cumulative sales of a specific product id >= 1000, the column takes a boolean value of 1, otherwise zero. However 1 can occur only once and after that the again always zero. Basically it's just an indicator of the date and transaction when a product sales exceeds the critical value of 1000.
- dw10perc: if the cumulative sales of one product id >= 10% of estimated lifetime value, the column takes value of 1, otherwise 0. However 1 can occur only once and after that the again always zero. Basically it's just an indicator of the date and transaction when a product sales exceeds the critical value of 10% of the estimated lifetime value.
- The threshold value is common for all product id's (I'll just replicate the process with different thresholds at a later stage to determine which is the optimal threshold to predict future revenue).

I'm trying to achieve this:
[image]

The code I've written so far is trying to establish the cum_rev and dw1k_thresh columns, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```py
df_final["dw1k_thresh"] = 0
df_final["cum_rev"]= 0 

opp_list =set()

for row in df_final["product id"].iteritems():
    opp_list.add(row)


opp_list=list(opp_list)
opp_list=pd.Series(opp_list)


for i in opp_list: 
    if i == df_final["product id"].any():
        df_final.cum_rev = df_final.revenue.cumsum()

    for x in df_final.cum_rev:
        if x >= 1000 & df_final.dw1k_thresh.sum() == 0: 
            df_final.dw1k_thresh = 1
        else: 
            df_final.dw1k_thresh = 0

df_final.head(30)
```

Comment: the threshold value is common for all products or it will change based on product_id?

Comment: I've added information to the question and also answered your question, so the threshold value is common for all products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Cumulative Revenue**: Can be calculated fairly simply with `groupby` and `cumsum`.
2. **dwk1k_thresh**: We are first checking whether cum_rev is greater than 1000 and then apply the function that helps us keep 1 **only once**, and after that the again always zero.
3. **dw10_perc**: Same approach as dw1k_thresh.

As a first step you would need to remove `$` and make sure your columns are of numeric type to perform the comparisons you outlined.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Remove $ sign and convert to numeric
cols = ['revenue','estimated lifetime value']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)

# Cumulative Revenue
df['cum_rev'] = df.groupby('product id')['revenue'].cumsum()

# Function to be applied on both
def f(df,thresh_col):
    return  (df[df[thresh_col]==1].sort_values(['date','product id'], ascending=False)
            .groupby('product id', as_index=False,group_keys=False)
            .apply(lambda x: x.tail(1))
            ).index.tolist()

# dw1k_thresh
df['dw1k_thresh'] = np.where(df['cum_rev'].ge(1000),1,0)
df['dw1k_thresh'] = np.where(df.index.isin(f(df,'dw1k_thresh')),1,0)

# dw10perc
df['dw10_perc'] = np.where(df['cum_rev'] > 0.10 * df.groupby('product id',observed=True)['estimated lifetime value'].transform('sum'),1,0)
df['dw10_perc'] = np.where(df.index.isin(f(df,'dw10_perc')),1,0)
```

Prints:

```
>>> df

        date          product id  revenue  ...  cum_rev  dw1k_thresh  dw10_perc
0 2021-04-16  0061M00001AXc5lQAD      970  ...      970            0          1
1 2021-04-17  0061M00001AXbCiQAL      159  ...      159            0          0
2 2021-04-18  0061M00001AXb9AQAT       80  ...       80            0          0
3 2021-04-19  0061M00001AXbIHQA1     1100  ...     1100            1          1
4 2021-04-20  0061M00001AXbY8QAL       90  ...       90            0          0
5 2021-04-21  0061M00001AXbQ1QAL       29  ...       29            0          0
6 2021-04-21  0061M00001AXc5lQAD       30  ...     1000            1          0
7 2021-05-02  0061M00001AXc5lQAD       50  ...     1050            0          0
8 2021-05-05  0061M00001AXc5lQAD       50  ...     1100            0          0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! 
One more thing, it seems like the code also looks forward in time. I would like it to only include the dates up until the specific row and based on that create a snapshot of that particular moment in history.

Comment: I'm using this as an input variable in creating a prediction algorithm, so it might otherwise cause problems in prediction performance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and glad you like it. What do you mean by "include the dates up until the specific row"? Which is the specific row and how is it signalled in the data?

Comment: I made a more detailed edit to the question. Could you have a look if you would be able to help me?

Comment: Hi, thanks for updating the question. I can of course have a look.

Comment: So you are trying to add those 3 columns at the end, right?

Comment: At the end works well, but the placement isn't that important. I'll use them in different statistical models and some feature importance algorithms.

Comment: To be sure I get it right, can you give me a clear description on how the last 2 columns, dwk1_thresh and dw10perc are calculated?

Comment: In my mind, the last 3 rows would also be 1 in dw1k_thresh, because the cumulative revenues of that product on those dates also exceeds it's estimated_lifetime_value.

Comment: dw1k_thresh: if the cumulative sales of a specific product id >=  1000, the column takes a boolean value of 1, otherwise zero. However 1 can occur only once and after that the again always zero. Basically it's just an indicator of the date and transaction when a product sales exceeds the critical value of 1000.

Comment: dw10perc: if the cumulative sales of one product id >= 10% of estimated lifetime value, the column takes value of 1, otherwise 0. However 1 can occur only once and after that the again always zero. Basically it's just an indicator of the date and transaction when a product sales exceeds the critical value of 10% of the estimated lifetime value.

Comment: The reason I want the boolean value of 1 to occur only once is that I'll aggregate this transaction data to daily / weekly revenue series in some cases. The win count is one of the main features I'll use to predict the future total revenue. Now if all values exceeding 1000 for one specific product would take 1 I would have highly inflated win counts and it couldn't be used as a feature to predict future revenue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231502/discussion-between-sophocles-and-alex-gunsberg).

Comment: @sophocles Nice answer. I really appreciate your efforts in helping the OP.

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamSharma. I appreciate it. I think part of the answer can be improved  and I will try to improve it, I just did not want the OP to wait for longer and gave a semi-ready answer :) . Thanks again

Comment: @sophocles Thank you so much!!! I would never have figured out the solution without your help!